# FormsAuthentication Sliding Expiration

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, formsauthentication

I have an `MVC 5` application that uses FormsAuthentication. 
On the `FormsAuthentication_OnAuthenticate()` function, event I create a new GenericIdentity with the current rights for the user.

```
protected void FormsAuthentication_OnAuthenticate(Object sender, FormsAuthenticationEventArgs e)
{
    if (FormsAuthentication.CookiesSupported)
            {
                var userInfo = AuthenticationHelper.GetUserInfo(Request.Cookies);
                if (userInfo != null)
                {
                    e.User = new GenericPrincipal(new GenericIdentity(userInfo.Username,"Forms"),userInfo.RightsStrings);
                }
            }
}
```

The configuration for the FormsAuthentication is :

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms timeout="2" loginUrl="~/Home/Login" slidingExpiration="true" cookieless="UseCookies"></forms>
</authentication>
```

The `slidingExpiration` option does not work when I assign the new GenericPrincipal.
If i comment that out the sliding expiration works but i cannot use the `[Authorize(Roles = "Role")]` syntax.

How can i accomplish both?

Comment: Why do you need to create a new generic identity?  Isn't this done for you by the framework and then stored in the User.Identity object?

Comment: I need it so I can add the rights string[] (userInfo.RightsStrings).

Comment: I don't have experience with what you are doing, but based on the names of your properties, it appears you are trying to solve the problem of giving certain rights/privileges to certain users.  Can't this be solved by simply using Asp.Net's built in support for groups and or adding columns onto the user object as shown here http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/10/16/customizing-profile-information-in-asp-net-identity-in-vs-2013-templates.aspx